# Изменение одной переменной при изменении другой

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

Почему при изменении списка a меняется и список b и как от этого избавиться?
Если изменить функцию с init на обычную, ничего не изменится.

```
class nibba():
    def __init__(self):
        a = [1, 2, 3]
        b = a
        a.append(4)
        print(b)     # [1, 2, 3, 4]
nibba = nibba()
```

Comment: они ссылаются на один и тот же объект. делайте так `b = a.copy()`

Comment: Можно брать срез всего списка. Срезы всегда создают новый объект: `b = a[:]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

списки, как и словари являются изменяемыми объектами, грубо если сделать так:

```py
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = a
a.pop()
print(a,b) -> [1, 2], [1, 2]
```

изменится не только a, но и b, так как они ссылаются на один объект в памяти.

чтобы такого не было принято идти по двум инструкциям:

```
b = a[:]
```

либо

```
b = a.copy()
```